# Composer RuntimeException - Could not load package mews/purifier

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have previously installed mews/purifier package and it was working fine. Now I want to update packages using `composer update`, this is where I get this error:

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                                             
  Could not load package mews/purifier in http://repo.packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException]  
   Could not parse version constraint ~4.*: Invalid version string "~4.*"
```

I already checked the package list and it has this package https://packagist.org/packages/mews/purifier

I tried to remove it from `composer.json` by removing this line:

```
"mews/purifier": "^3.2",
```

But the error persists. I also removed associated lines in the `app.php` file.

```
'providers' => [
Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider::class
],
'aliases' => [
'Purifier' => Mews\Purifier\Facades\Purifier::class
]
```

I really don't know what the problem is here. It all began when I wanted to install a package and I realized this issue.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using this command solved the problem:

```
composer self-update
```

or if you don't have the permission:

```
sudo composer self-update
```

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer helped me. You get my upvote. Thanks.